# How to sort only the right quarter of a 10 x 10 matrix?

Tags: c++, sorting, matrix, multidimensional-array, logic

10x10 matrix which is divided into 4 parts, the right quarter is sorted by the *any_method* in rows:

[image: Picture: 10x10 matrix which is divided into 4 parts, the right quarter is sorted by the *any_method* in rows.]

I am a beginner. I totally do not understand how algorithm of picking the right quarter for its further sorting really works. Here is what I have at the moment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
srand(time(0));

const int size = 10;
int matrix[size][size];
int sum = 0;

system("mode con cols=100 lines=70");

cout << "Source matrix 10x10" << endl;
cout << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        matrix[i][j] = rand() % 50;   
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        cout << matrix[i][j] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}

cout << endl;
cout << "Transformed matrix 10x10" << endl;

int temp;
int k = 0;
int cond = 0;

for (int s = 0; s < size; s++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = size - 1; j > i; j--)
        {    
            if (matrix[s][j] < matrix[s][j - 1])
            {
                temp = matrix[s][j];
                matrix[s][j] = matrix[s][j - 1];
                matrix[s][j - 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        cout << matrix[i][j] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}

cout << endl << sum << endl;

return 0;
system("pause");

}
```

Comment: In order to get answers, you need to give us more information, some code maybe (or at least signatures), something to better understand the problem.
Please read the [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section!

Comment: Yeah, sorry i have forgotten to paste it, when i started... I edited it just right now

Comment: What is `any_method`? Please reorganize your code (put all things inside of functions) so it will be easier to understand (for both us and **you**)

Comment: It means any method you can choose. I picked bubble sort for instance.

Comment: Okay, it is clearer. Also, why do you use the command `system("mode con cols=100 lines=70");`?

Comment: You can still clarify your question even more.

Comment: You can skip it actually. It is just a console window height and width. It isnot influencing the code.

Comment: Are the rows sorted indipendently or an element can be swapped between different rows?

Comment: No, only by the rows.

Comment: Is your question how to sort, or is it just how to pick out the region to be sorted? (Before you start sorting, you might want to initialize the matrix to all zeros, then try to set each entry in the right quarter to 1.)

Comment: I have got some problems with how actually i am going to pick the region of the right quarter. So choosing the right quarter higher in priority then sorting.

Comment: So, for every row, can you select (evaluate the indices of) the elements on the two diagonals and the last in the row?

Comment: @Dmtr Then I would recommend removing all mention of sorting from your question. Focus on finding the right quarter. (However, I've rethought my earlier suggestion. Initialize each entry of the matrix to `-1` instead of `0` and have a goal of setting each entry in the right quarter to its row number. Try to do this, then update your question with the new code, the new expected result, and the new actual result.)

Answer (score 3):

> I have got some problems with how actually i am going to pick the
>   region of the right quarter. So choosing the right quarter higher in
>   priority then sorting

I've used [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) to demonstrate *sorting the **right quarter** of a 10 x 10 matrix*.

My logic is explained in the code comments:

```
void sortRightQuarter(int m[10][10])
{
    /*
    Indexes of the elements in the Right Quarter
                                    (0, 9) // already sorted
                            (1, 8), (1, 9) // i = 1, k = 8
                    (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9) // i = 2, k = 7
            (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9) // i = 3, k = 6
    (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9) // i = 4, k = 5
    (5, 5), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9) // i = 5, k = 5
            (6, 6), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9) // i = 6, k = 6
                    (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9) // i = 7, k = 7
                            (8, 8), (8, 9) // i = 8, k = 8
                                    (9, 9) // already sorted
    */

    // Sort the rows [1, 8]
    int k = 8;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; ++i)
    {
        // pick your favorite sorting function
        // to sort elements in the range [m[i][k], last element of the row]
        sort(&m[i][k], &m[i][10]);

        // change the value of k
        if (i < 4)
            --k;
        else
            ++k;
    }
}
```

I used your code to test my function. Works good.

Comment: See the link, you should `#include <algorithm>` in order to use `std::sort`

Answer (score 1):

Consider splitting your code into smaller functions, but to accomplish your task, all you need to do is to apply a sorting function to the appropriate part of each row in the matrix:

```
for (int i = 0,     // Index of the row and the column of the elements on the main diagonal
     j = size - 1;  // Column of the element on the anti-diagonal
     i < size;
     ++i, --j)
{        
    int *row = &matrix[i][0];                      // Start of the row
    std::sort(row + std::max(i, j), row + size);
    //              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Pick the right one
}
```

Also note the end of the program

```
return 0;
system("pause");   // <-- How this could be executed? Not that it should, BTW.
```

Answer (score 1):

Let `M` be a matrix of size `K x K`, such `K` must be either:

1. A `K` such as `k = 2 * n` where `n` is a non-negative integer.
2. A `K` such as `k = 2 * n + 1` where `n` is a non-negative integer.

Now to solve the algorithmic part of getting only the part in the rightmost quarter; Denote `row` and `col` as the row and column numbers.

**Case 1:**

for `row <= n` the needed cells are of `col >= k - row + 1`

for `row >= n + 1` the needed cells are of `col >= row`

**Case 2:**

for `row <= n + 1` the needed cells are of `col >= k - row + 1`

for `row > n + 1` the needed cells are of `col >= row`

How can you get to this? Simply sit with a paper, draw a matrix, and look at the needed cells. Determine what are the "key points" where the rule changes, and you will get your answer.